# Shopping system for event photography

Tags: business, selling, event-photography

What are some recommendations for a system that I can sell my photos on?

For example I go to an event and take picture and give my card to people who want to see their pictures...then in my site I create different parts for different events, people can see and download their pics in a smaller size good enough for Facebook, with my transparent logo maybe on bottom right, then they click buy to pay for example $5.00 to download the same image with no logo and in bigger size and maybe even $15.00 to receive the RAW format of the image.
I also want it to have a front page that I can demo my work so they see my portfolio too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the commercial gallery sites support this kind of sale. I've worked with Smugmug for a few years and a number of their customers do exactly this kind of event sale. Others that you could do it with would include Photoshelter and (I think) Shutterfly.